# Linq datatype mismatch issue

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use the following in my linq query:

```
name_9 = data.Field<String>("Line Description") == "Care" ? "" : data.Field<DateTime>("End Date")
```

However, when I try to, I get the following error;

> Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
>   there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.DateTime'

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The end-date is a datetime, not a string; a simple approach might be:

```
name_9 = data.Field<String>("Line Description") == "Care" ?
       "" : data.Field<DateTime>("End Date").ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `.ToString()` method. It's a `datetime`, not `string`.

```
data.Field<DateTime>("End Date").ToString()
```